# Manage state in Cosmos DB instead of in-memory for Bot to Human handover scenario

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I am working on a bot with human handover features (Human-2-Human chat), where bot is in charge of whole communication. The user can start the communication with bot and if he is not satisfied by bot's responses, he can ask for further assistance from Human.

Bot is able to connect the user to a live Agent using a Third Party System. Bot forwards the message from a dialog to an API endpoint of this system along with a callback url. This third party system uses a callback mechanism to pass the message written by agent on this specified url.

I have created an API Controller endpoint and pass to this system as callback url. When agent sends a message the system notifies on this endpoint. It is simple Web API controller with no direct affiliation to Bot Framework.

Although I maintain a Conversation and User State of the bot in Cosmos DB and it has certain properties that contain status of chat connection like (ChatConnected, ChatClosed etc). Now to pass these message notifications to bot I maintain two concurrent dictionary one for Conversation Reference and second for TurnContext.

- Conversation Reference helps to pass the agent message from bot to user using ContinueConversationAsync.
- TurnContext helps to manage and update the state of these properties when session closed etc. And also use it to send message after certain period of inactivity since last turn has activity timestamp.

Now both of these are in-memory, which means they are added and removed as new chat sessions are created and as more messages are exchanged. I now want to move this out from in-memory to a shared cache or low latency cosmos. So that I can also use the possibility of auto-scaling new instances of bot service when required. I am using appservices currenly. But due to this coupling new instances don't have access to in-memory data, and therefore can not service. I don't think that enabling AffinityCookie for Bot Scenarios actually works.

I am able to serialize the ConversationReference object (through NewtonSoft), but serializing TurnContext throws JSON serialization exception due to internal loop in object. I tried to mitigate that with SerilizationSettings to ignore loop but it does not even works in VS during debugging throws VS stack overflow exception.

So how can I move this code to become independent of singleton ConcurrentDictionary on an instance-

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ITurnContext> TurnContextReferences;


private void AddTurnContext(ITurnContext turnContext, string sessionId)
        {
            if (turnContext != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionId))
            {
                //Add the Session Id and TurnContext to dictionary
                TurnContextReferences.AddOrUpdate(sessionId, turnContext, (key, newValue) => turnContext);
            }
        }
```

```
//Using above method inside a function
//Trim the incoming message
                    var userMessage = messageActivity.Text.Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userMessage))
                    {
                        //send the incoming message from client to Agent
                        await TPSystem.SendMessageAsync(messageActivity.Conversation.Id, conversationData.SessionId, messageActivity.Text.Trim());
                        
                    }
                    //Add to Turn context Dictionary
                    AddTurnContext(stepContext.Context, conversationData.SessionId);
```

```
//Inside API Controller
 //Get the TurnContext from the Dictionary
                            TurnContextReferences.TryGetValue(sessionStateChangedEventData.SessionId, out ITurnContext turnContext);

                            if (turnContext != null)
                            {
                                var conversationData = await BotStateAccessors.ConversationStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationStateDataModel());
                                if (!conversationData.LiveAgentChatClosed)
                                {
                                    conversationData.LiveAgentChatClosed = true;
                                    await BotStateAccessors.ConversationStateAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, conversationData);
                                    await BotConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
                                }
                            }
```

Any ideas to think through would be appreciated.

Comment: Does h2h mean "human to human" or "handoff to human" or what?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, it means "human to human" but "handoff to human" is also correct.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, if my questions needs anymore clarification or is not clear. Please feel free to comment, I will correct it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. It's a bit more clear now, but still pretty lengthy. I don't think TJ will be able to see where you @-mentioned him since he hasn't commented on this question, and asking for help from specific people generally isn't a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversation references contain a subset of the information in activities, and an activity is just one property of a turn context, so a conversation reference contains a subset of the information in a turn context. It's redundant to be saving both conversation references and turn contexts because if you save turn contexts then you'll already have all the information from the conversation references.

That said, it's a very bad idea to try to save turn contexts. If you need some pieces of information that aren't in the conversation references then just save that specific information. For example, you can create your own class that contains a conversation reference and a timestamp that signifies the time of the last message from that conversation.

```
public class ConversationInfo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "conversationReference")]
    public ConversationReference ConversationReference { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I do understand that keeping turn context is not really the best thing to do, but the problem is I need to do this update the state which requires turncontext.

Comment: That's incorrect. All the information you need to save state is in the conversation reference. I recommend upvoting and accepting this answer and then asking a new question that explains why you think you need to save a turn context in order to update state and asks how you can update state without a turn context.

Comment: I think ConversationReference contains the relevant information to send a message using Continue Conversation since it has Service URL etc. But TurnContext has the actual TurnState dictionary which is updated and persisted to Cosmos. Also I don't just have to write a new state property or new document which is usually as good as writing directly to Cosmos. There are certain examples out there in docs. But I have to fetch and update a property in the actual bot state, I have added few additional properties using custom ConversationDataModel. So don't think it is possible without TurnContext.

Comment: It's very strange to me that you prefer to insist something is impossible instead of asking how to do it. I cannot help people who refuse to be helped.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend. And thankful for your responses. But I think I have to know more on how it would be possible without TurnContext and also confer on its applicability to the underlying implementation I have. If you have any information, I can quickly double check and take the direction forward.

Comment: You still have not asked a question for me to answer. Your original post contained no questions and none of your follow-up comments have contained any questions. I recommended that you make a new post and you have not done that. I already explained that "If you need some pieces of information that aren't in the conversation references then just save that specific information." If you need some specific information from the turn state for example then you should save just that instead of the whole turn context. Please ask a new question if you need help doing that instead of using comments.

Comment: I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549612/how-to-manage-and-store-turnstate-without-using-turncontext-object) today. Once I have a comprehensible answer, will accept to benefit others. Thanks

Comment: I got distracted from this work for a while but back into this again. I have implemented the suggestion of creating a model class with ConversationReference and some additional properties that I would require from Activity class. Thus, it becomes light weight and serializable for storing in Cosmos DB. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AmitC - I'm glad to hear it. Thank you for the update