# How to manage and store TurnState without using TurnContext object

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

In following piece of code, TurnContext object is required to fetch the underlying Bot State from Cosmos and save it back -

```
//Get the TurnContext from the Dictionary
TurnContextReferences.TryGetValue(sessionStateChangedEventData.SessionId, out ITurnContext turnContext);
if (turnContext != null)
{
    var conversationData = await BotStateAccessors
                      .ConversationStateAccessor
                      .GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationStateDataModel());
    if (!conversationData.LiveAgentChatClosed)
    {
        conversationData.LiveAgentChatClosed = true;
        await BotStateAccessors.ConversationStateAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, conversationData);
        await BotConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to achieve same without using TurnContext directly?

Comment: Thank you for the question. So to be clear, you have a dictionary of turn contexts that you're using to load conversation state and then save it again while you're not processing an actual user-initiated turn. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, this is correct. This code is part of a NotificationController which receives some events from a 3rd Party System and based on it,  need to update the state and pass the message back to user (if any).

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I think I have got your point but just to reiterate what you are suggesting is that using ContinueConversationAsync callback or inside it we should obtain the TurnContext and then get the Property Accessor and update state. But this also means using the ContinueConversationAsync in code at the places where the state is being updated. Is it recommended, I did notice at a place where I am sending an activity back to user, I already use this pattern. So its just a matter of finding out if it is okay to use ContinueConversationAsync in other places of Controller.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I see another problem that the turnContext obtained inside callback of ContinueConversationAsync does have most properties null. While the turnContext I maintain has the Locale, Activity TimeStamp, Message etc inside it. But this code gives me null can I assign these properties someway before adding the conversationReference in dictionary -
await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)HttpAdapter).ContinueConversationAsync(MSAppId, conversationReferenceItem.ConversationReference, async (context, token) =>
                                    { var locale = context?.Activity?.Locale }

Comment: I still feel like we're dealing with an XY problem here. In order to get a satisfactory answer, you will eventually need to explain what you're actually trying to do and why.  Nothing in your question indicates that you'd need a timestamp, and I still don't understand why you would. But the data hierarchy is context -> activity -> conversation reference. That means an activity contains everything a conversation reference contains and more. It's possible that you could solve your problem by saving activities instead of turn contexts or conversation references.

Comment: The details of what I am trying to do are on the parent questions from where this was created [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206530/manage-state-in-cosmos-db-instead-of-in-memory-for-bot-to-human-handover-scenari)

Comment: You explained that you're trying to do bot-to-human handoff, but that doesn't explain why you need more properties that are contained in a conversation reference. A conversation reference has everything you need for handoffs. Is saving activities an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need to access bot state and send messages to a user is in a conversation reference. You can build a turn context out of a saved conversation reference using the `ContinueConversationAsync` method. You can see how to do this in the [proactive messages sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L44):

```
await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
```

A turn context is not meant to exist outside of its associated turn. You should be saving conversation references instead of turn contexts.